# Is it possible to prevent MKMapView from loading tiles until view is visible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, mkmapview, lag

Is it possible to prevent MKMapView from loading tiles until view is visible ? Or rather postpone it ?

I have somewhat complex view where user can switch between list view, photo view and map view using Segmented Control.

Default mode is list view therefore photo view and map view have their `hidden` property set to `YES`.

But despite being hidden I see that `MKMapView` is loading tiles every time I load my complex view :( It results in quite noticeable lag (~900 ms) which I confirmed in Instruments using time profiling.

I tried to subclass `MKMapView` and override `didAddSubview`, `willMoveToSuperview`, `didMoveToSuperview`, `willMoveToWindow` and `didMoveToWindow` with hope of using any of these calls to catch the moment map view really becomes visible.

I also tried to use methods of delegate of `MKMapView`. Unfortunately they're also called before map view becomes visible.

What would you suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just not create it until the segmented control is pressed. Rather than having it in IB, leave an empty space and when the control is switched check if mapView is nil, if so create it, add it to the view and continue as planned.

Comment: Thanks! Yep, I ended up doing just that. I also realized that all my view are created from scratch every time I navigate using segue. Fixed that as well.